# HTTP Status 404 description The requested resource () is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am a beginner in Java EE. I am working with Eclipse Helios 3.6.2 and Tomcat 7.
I have created a dynamic web project with JSF 2.0. 
When I run a simple page, there is an error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /first/
type Status report
message /first/
description The requested resource (/first/) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

Code:

```or-tag-here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>first page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my project?
How can I deploy the project?
should i change `<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">`?

Comment: don't know much about eclipse, but the problem is, Tomcat does not know your Context 'first'. To fix this you have to deploy the context. Read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html#Deployment_With_Tomcat for details. There may be a different way of 'reply during development' with eclipse (there is one wit IntelliJ Idea), but as I said: I don't know about eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  downloaded eclipse and tomcat and tested a new dynamic web project with the following steps:

1) Added tomcat in servers

2) Created dynamic web project with the target runtime as Apache tomcat.

3) Created a new dummy jsp

4) Right clicked on project and selected Run on Server .

I could see the dummy page.

Comment: where did you create your jsp? under web-inf?

Comment: i create html page(start-page) under web-inf. and all of those you mentioned. but still i have http status 404.

Comment: created under WebContent folder

Answer (score 0):

you need to add tomcat server in eclipse , and then deploy the project

Comment: i did. i defined the new server.

Comment: and then in your project properties did you set the target server as tomcat

Comment: now when you right click on your project and select deploy do you see any thing in your output window

Comment: when i right click in my project(first) and choose run on server, the http status 404 appears.

Comment: but when i go to workspace/first/webcontent/web-inf/first-page.html is excist and runs

Comment: downloading eclipse to test this scenario give me 10 mins :)